# HTML coding to authenticate user in the websites

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I am having a doubt regarding whether it is possible to authenticate the user with html coding? If it is, I want the html script to authenticate user in my website. Or it is enough to tell me the websites which is offering free user authentication.

with regards
Anand

Comment: use javascript but are your usernames and password in database? if so then this is not a good practice

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use pure HTML to create an authentication system, and using client-side JavaScript is not a good idea, for security reasons. To make the authentication system reliable you would have to involve some kind of server-side language like ASP.NET, PHP, Ruby or similar.

If you don't want to do it your self, there are plenty of CMS solutions that has built-in authentication. You could either choose a hosted solution like [Wordpress](http://wordpress.com/) or you could pick any CMS solution you like and host it on your own.

Here are a few to choose from:

- http://www.orchardproject.net/ (ASP.NET)
- http://drupal.org/ (PHP)
- http://wordpress.org/ (PHP)

Microsoft also offer a free hosting solution for [Azure websites](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/), where they offer a simple click-to-setup service for a large number of CMS solutions, including above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

password and username authentication using javascript is a very bad idea, anyone could just bypass it through your html file or js file. You should use PHP and PDO or mySqli in authenticating users.

Answer (score 0):

```
HyperText Markup Language (HTML) is the main markup language for displaying web pages and other information that can be displayed in a web browser.
```

HTML is just used to output something for the users. You cannot make an authentication system with HTML.

The best and the easiest way of authenticating, is to combine HTML with PHP. You can also do it with any other `server side programming language`.

You can checkout PHP Login systems, which are very reliable. You can surely grab code snippets that you can use as is.

Comment: Are you saying that PHP login systems are more reliable than those built on other languages? In that case, it would be nice with a reference on that.

Comment: It was more of like, I meant PHP Login systems are very reliable. Will edit the answer now ha ha. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not possible, how about OpenID?